How to normally output a path containing non-English characters in Popen
it's my function code
~~~~sql
DO
$$
 from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
 import os
 import sys
 
 env = os.environ.copy()
 reload(sys)
 sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
 plpy.notice(sys.getdefaultencoding())
 command = 'hdfs dfs -ls /workspace/테스트/'
 ls = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout= PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env=env)
 stdout,stderr = ls.communicate()
 plpy.notice(stdout)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu

the corresponding error is output.
ls: '/workspace/??????' : No such file or directory

No matter how many times you try encoding or decoding, the file name is broken only in Hadoop's command.
ex)mkdir -p 테스트 like a works well in console
plpythonu's python version : 2.7

What exactly are you trying to do? HDFS has to use utf8 filenames, I think
